# Python Queue and threading issue

Tags: python, multithreading, conditional-statements, deque

Looking for some guidance on solving what looks like a simple problem but has burnt many many hours of my life. I've reduced it to a single test case: I'm trying to add items to a queue in the main thread and read them from a different thread, and for some reason this simply doesn't work. The test class is below:

```
from collections import deque
import Queue
import threading
from threading import Thread
from threading import Lock
from threading import Condition
from pprint import pformat
from time import sleep

class UpdateIndex(Thread):
        def __init__(self):
                Thread.__init__(self)

                # A flag to notify the thread that it should finish up and exit
                self.kill_received = False

                # make it a daemon so it doesn't block
                self.daemon = True

                # queue
                self.indexqueue = deque()
                self.available = Lock()

                self.__class__.processor = self


        def add(self, document):
                with self.available:
                        self.indexqueue.append(document)
                        print "Added: "+str(len(self.indexqueue)) + " to "+hex(id(self.indexqueue))

        @classmethod
        def update(cls, document):
                cls.processor.add(document)

        def run(self):
                sleeptime = 1
                while self.kill_received == False:
                        sleeptime = 1.0
                        with self.available:
                                print "Checking: "+str(len(self.indexqueue)) + " in "+hex(id(self.indexqueue))
                                while len(self.indexqueue) > 0:
                                        sleeptime = 0
                                        source = self.indexqueue.popleft()

                                        print "===>Updating "+pformat(source)

                        if sleeptime > 0:
                                sleep(sleeptime)


if __name__ == "__main__":
        indexthread = UpdateIndex()
        indexthread.start()

        sleep(2)

        UpdateIndex.update({ "id": "one" })
        sleep(5)
        UpdateIndex.update({ "id": "two" })
        sleep(5)
        UpdateIndex.update({ "id": "three" })
```

The output I see is this:

```
Checking: 0 in 0xb71118ecL
Checking: 0 in 0xb71118ecL
Added: 1 to 0xb71118ecL
Checking: 1 in 0xb71118ecL
===>Updating {'id': 'one'}
Checking: 0 in 0xb71118ecL
Checking: 0 in 0xb71118ecL
Checking: 0 in 0xb71118ecL
Checking: 0 in 0xb71118ecL
Checking: 0 in 0xb71118ecL
Added: 1 to 0xb71118ecL
Checking: 1 in 0xb71118ecL
===>Updating {'id': 'two'}
Checking: 0 in 0xb71118ecL
Checking: 0 in 0xb71118ecL
Checking: 0 in 0xb71118ecL
Checking: 0 in 0xb71118ecL
Checking: 0 in 0xb71118ecL
Added: 1 to 0xb71118ecL
```

For some reason, the second thread never sees the additions to the deque. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: also, super confusing for me was the fact that the deque size is always one. There appears to be something emptying it, but I can't for the life of me figure out what. I'm printing out the id of the deque just to make sure we're dealing with the same object, and it appears to be the same from the main thread as well as from the update thread.

EDIT: just realized that the test case above seems to work fine, but the exact same class added to my Django project gives this:

```
Checking: 0 in 0x982e614
Checking: 0 in 0x982e614
Checking: 0 in 0x982e614
Added: 1 to 0x982e614
Checking: 0 in 0x982e614
Checking: 0 in 0x982e614
```

Now I'm even more confused.

Comment: I don't see what's surprising about the deque length never getting above one.  `popleft` *pops* the leftmost element off your deque and returns it.  Thus your `run` method will always consume the entire deque.

Comment: Sorry, didn't include the entire problem. Sleep deprived. The test case actually works fine. When I copy the class into my Django project and run it from a custom command that's where I'm seeing the error I added to my edit above.

Comment: have you considered using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery ? it might take away all this hassle away and let you sleep better :)

Comment: @Femi I see.  Well, I have to think the problem is external to the code you've posted.  Maybe you have a zombie worker thread that is still consuming from the `UpdateIndex` class' queue?  All I can think of, sorry, not too familiar with Django, past knowing it exists and is something people theoretically use.

Comment: @roippi: looking at that now. There might be some other environmental factors at play: the hex(id) addresses look weird, too. This is all in a virtualenv, so should be perfectly reproducible, but.... Guy: already using django-rq, and that works fine. I just needed to ensure the index updates don't block that.

Comment: @Femi djanog celery is not about queueing, it has a perfect producer -> worker/s paradigm, all you'll have to do is notating the function you want to run in another process with @task, worker are listening to the queue in another process, run it using `celery worker....` there's some installation overhead involved but it works flowlessly